# Downloding files via SFTP on MobaXterm gets stuck when filenames are in Hebrew

Tags: sftp, utf-8, characters, mobaxterm

When I try to download files whose names Hebrew characters, the download gets stuck and shows an error:

`Error EInOutError: I/O error 123`

[image]

How do I fix this? I don't want to use another FTP client, I am looking for a solution that will enable me to use MobaXterm.